# LIMIT CELLS PER ROW IN JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

please i want to display some products from database in a jsp page , i used a table to display them , and it display all the products in a single row , i want to limit the number of cells ( td ) per row , for example 5 per row .. 
here is the reuslt i get [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbwIw.png)

and here is the code i used 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a46mA.png)

THANK U

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open and close the row by

```
<tr></tr>
```

And iterate through your rows when it reaches your desired total then break out of the loop

Comment: Great, next time post the code instead of screenshots ;) easier to try and help you with the code.